# Enervating Mist vs Silent Wobby, which one is active?

Tags: yu-gi-oh

I recently asked myself a random question, what would happen if [Enervating Mist](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Enervating_Mist) (handsize down to 5) and [Silent Wobby](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Silent_Wobby) (limit handsize to 3) were active at the same time. Would it just be last or first one (based on activation order)?

Comment: Enervating mist seems to decrease hand size also (opponent hand size to 5), Infinite Cards is, as far as I know, the only card that gives unlimited hand size

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ruling](https://yugioh.fandom.com/wiki/Card_Rulings:Enervating_Mist) on Enervating Mist I see the following, emphasis mine:

> If "Enervating Mist" and "Infinite Cards" are both active, **whichever effect resolved last is dominant**.

So yes, it will depend on the order of activation (and thus, order of resolution) which effect takes place.

A related fact is the "negative precedence over positive" rule (as in MTG IIRC). This means that if an effect says that someone *can* do X, and another effect says that someone *cannot* do X (they contradict each other), the cannot takes precedence over the can.

This is not the case for the specific cards you mentioned, but is worth mentioning nonetheless.